# Does AWS reuse Account IDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have multiple AWS accounts in our company. We give lots of cross-account accesses to AWS resources on these accounts.

What happens to the cross-account policies in an Account if the other account is closed?

1. Are the policies automatically updated in the source account? or is it expected from the source account owners to update the policies/access?
2. Is the account number assigned to the closed account re-used in any way for any other account by AWS? If yes, this could be a security issue. Right?

Comment: Not really a programming problem. This is probably better asked on [SF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Account numbers are not reused. The Account ID is unique to each account.

Answer (score 2):

No AWS never reused account number, Because AWS never delete your account. When you delete your account that time AWS only disable your account not delete it.